# How can I make a cube in Three.js having the 4 vertex of the base and a given height?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have this json with the base coords, I need to render a cube in Threeejs out of it. The height is a given constant (let's say 1 in this case).

```json
        {
            "points": [
                {
                    "x": 0,
                    "y": 0,
                    "z": 0
                },
                {
                    "x": 0,
                    "y": -1,
                    "z": 0
                },
                {
                    "x": 1,
                    "y": 0,
                    "z": 0
                },
                {
                    "x": 1,
                    "y": -1,
                    "z": 0
                }
            ]
        }
```

What geometry should I use in Three.js?

I have tried using ExtrudeGeometry but the cube rendered was rendered incorrectly (missing top) and with wrong base coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with this code:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';

let renderer, scene, camera;

const data = {
    "points": [
        {
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "z": 0
        },
        {
            "x": 0,
            "y": -1,
            "z": 0
        },
        {
            "x": 1,
            "y": -1,
            "z": 0
        },
    {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 0,
            "z": 0
        },
    ]
};

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100 );
    camera.position.set( 5, 2, 5 );
    
    const shape = new THREE.Shape();
    
    shape.moveTo( 0, 0 ); // first point
    
    for ( let i = 1, l = data.points.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
    
      const point = data.points[ i ];
      shape.lineTo( point.x, point.y );
    
    }
    
    const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, { depth: 1, bevelEnabled: false } );
    geometry.center(); // optional
    const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    
}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

You have to watch out to define the contour of the base in CCW order.

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gmxo6td2/